# Html PHP combining

Tags: php, html

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to combine `html` and `php` codes.

Such as

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DATA goes here : <?php echo something_number("$total");?> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there other methods to declare `php` in a `html` line???
thanks for the help by the ways.

```
<?php

include ('db.php');
set_time_limit(0); // set unlimited execution time
ini_set("memory_limit","1000M");
```

Comment: if this code file is having `.html` extension then it will not work. You have to change it to `.php` and also you have `apache` with `php` to run this code (That means xampp/wamp/lampp/mamp anyone of this is install into your system (based on OS) and properly configured)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can also use short echo tag `<?= ... ?>`

```
<td>DATA goes here : <?=something_number("$total");?> </td>
```

You can use this tag to print something. But for program logics, you should use `<?php ... ?>` tag. You can read more about PHP tags [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

---

**Note:** *(From the perspective of [Anant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4248328/anant))* Whenever you have PHP code inside HTML. The file extension should be `.php` and not `.html`

Comment: if this code file is having `.html` extension then it will not work. You have to change it to `.php` and also you have `apache` with `php` to run this code (That means xampp/wamp/lampp/mamp anyone of this is install into your system (based on OS) and properly configured)

Comment: OP has asked about _Is there other methods to declare php in a html line_. Not about the extension issue.

Comment: @Anant that is not what the OP asked. And this answer should not be downvoted as it is completely correct.

Comment: Before using this code you must have to check for enabling php options of 'short open tag' & 'asp tags' in php.ini file.

Comment: you can easily config apache to serve html files with php

Comment: @KinjalMistry Please read this sentence from PHP manual ___5.4.0 The tag <?= is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting.___

Comment: @Thamilan It's only after 5.4.0, if there is previous version one should have to perform the action for enabling short open tag option

Comment: @Thamilan The file extension is     .php     , but when I try to run the full coding, the result came out as though the query return to no result.

Comment: @Thamilan That is the full coding

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your PHP in files that have an HTML extension, and you're using Apache, you can add this to the server configuration or (if the server is configured to allow it) create a file called `.htaccess` in your webroot and add this line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

That will allow your php to run in an `.html` file.

---

Depending on which version of PHP you're using and how it's configured, there may be several available substitutes for the usual `<?php ?>`.

If you're using PHP<7 you can also use `<script language="php"> </script>` without any configuration changes.

If shorttags is enabled, you can use `<? ?>`, but this is not usually turned on by default in an out of the box *AMP stack.

ASP style tags aren't often used or recommended, but with proper config you can also use `<% %>`

This is also supported out of the box for **outputting** inline, not for running code`<?= ?>`. This is shorthand for `<?php echo ...; ?>`

If ASP style tags are enabled you can use this shorthand for outputting `<%= %>`.

***Generally, for compatibility and convenience, I would recommend sticking to `<?php and ?>`.***

---

For some good info read:

- [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)
- [PHP Tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)
- [Running PHP from other file types](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-under-a-different-file-extension)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you have got your answer and yes you should use `<?php ...... ?>` And also you can use short hand notation too, but I would not recommend that.
 And you have to have .PHP extension in your file to use PHP methods and write PHP code.

Also you can put html code as well in .PHP files.

Thanks